# Issue on mysqldump in MySQL5.6

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.6

I did upgrade the MySQL server from `5.5` to `5.6`

I am trying to take dump for a table like this

```
 mysqldump -uroot -p dba admin > D:\admin.sql
```

But it gets following error

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1':
> You have an er  ror in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server v  ersion for the right syntax to use
> near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line  1 (1064)

## edit:

mysqldump verison is 5.5.30.

Comment: I suspect you updated your server but forgot to update the clients. What is the version of mysqldump?

Answer (score 2):

Some information can be found in [SET Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html) and this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67507).

> The SET statement assigns values to different types of variables that affect the operation of the server or your client. Older versions of MySQL employed SET OPTION, but this syntax is deprecated in favor of SET without OPTION.

## How to fix it

- **If the problem happens when you are creating the dump (your case)**:
  Upgrade you MySQL client tools to the same version of your MySQL server (in your case, 5.6)
- **If the problem happens when you are restoring the dump**: At the beginning of the file, you have some `SET OPTION` statements; edit your dump, and change all instances of `SET OPTION` to `SET SESSION` like described [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66765)

Comment: and from where? I can't find it for windows mysql 5.6...